# Bamboo 3/8" hardwood nailer

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, hardwood

I am having a hard time finding a nailer that take cleats and has a plate for 3/8 hardwood bamboo.  Could I use either 1/4 or 1/2 plates?  This is my first time nailing down a hardwood floor and want to do it right.

Comment: Sorry done from my phone.  Updated.

Comment: Ok, but it looks like you still have several typos--two spelling and one punctuation. Please respect your audience. :)

Comment: If you already have a nailgun and floorboards in your possession, you could do a test: put a scrap of floorboard onto the subfloor (or a piece of the same type of plywood or OSB that's in your house) and nail it with both the 1/4 and 1/2 plates, and see whether either one looks OK. If neither one works, you may be able to slip a 1/8 shim between the foot of the nailgun and the 1/4 plate, but test that even more carefully because you don't want any trouble while using it for actual nailing.